# How can I put my simulation result into a .txt file when it is an array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython, simulation

I simulated a model with this script and now I just want to substitute T1 with a symbol t1 in a text file

How should change the T1 from array to something else so that I can substitute that ?

```
from pymodelica import compile_fmu
        from pyfmi import load_fmu
        # Import the plotting library
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import numpy as np
        # Compile model
        model_name = 'Testerequal'
        mo_file = 'Testerequal.mo'
        VDP_fmu = compile_fmu('Testerequal', compiler_options = {'extra_lib_dirs':'D:\JModelica.org-1.17\Testerequal'})
        # Load model
        vdpid = load_fmu(VDP_fmu, log_level=7)
        res = vdpid.simulate(final_time=86400)

        x0= res["int.y"]
        t0= res["time"]

        T1 = x0[40] 

    f = open('D:/JModelica.org-1.17/Testertwo/That.txt','r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close() 

    newdata = filedata.replace('t1',T1)

    f = open('D:/JModelica.org-1.17/Testertwo/That.txt','w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

Comment: What format do you need? A CSV?

Comment: the format is not a deal for me,as far as I can substitute that with a letter in a text file it would be enough.

Comment: what I'm doing is not complicated, I got some results from a simulation and they are x0 and t0, each of them(x0 and t0)includes some numbers so that for example if I type x0[5] I got 234, if I type x0[40] I got 567 as the output,so I prepared a text file which cosists of some alphabets with numbers > t0,t1,t2,t3........ ,                                                        I just want to substitute each value of x0 for example x0[40] in t0.... the script is ok basically the only thing is that python will give error when I try to substite the said value(x0[4]) into t0(in my text file).

Comment: @Schollii is it possible for you to just review this and tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: I understand what x0 and t0 are, that's the easy part. As mentioned in my comment, show what filedata is, and show the exact script you use, and show the exception traceback etc. Also, the indentation in what you posted is wrong so we can't tell what you script actually is. Since I don't have pymodellica installed, you have to be extra attentive to detail as I have no way of running what you post. Edit all this in your post, not in comments. There's already too many comments in this threads, makes it hard to read. Post should be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: @Schollii don't take this the wrong way but if you are professional programmer working with lots of stuff then this kinda questions should be a piece of cake for you,so let's suppose that this question is too trivial for you so you just force me to apply thousands of details and in the end you don't even bother to answer while few days later somebody answered that perfectly,so if you are dealing with incomplete question how did Christian Andersson(below) could answer that? the first call for modification was ok but again and again... is not helpful....

Comment: let's try to solve the things not just modifying the problems.                                   P.S. I'm not a dumb guy who is trying to learn how to read a book or ask a question on the internet...my field wasn't python programming that is why I'm here to ask people who already used python alot.

Comment: The less clear a question, the fewer people can answer. Sometimes you get lucky and someone comes along a week later and happens to  understand the question although no one else did, figures out the problem, finds the solution, and posts it. That's why SO is SO. Welcome to SO and keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to substitute an string with a numpy float.

The variable x0 in your case is a numpy array of floats and thus T1 is a numpy float. Now when you try to substitute t1 it will give you an error due to that T1 is not a string. If you just want to substitute the value of T1 for t1, just convert it to a string, i.e.:

```
    filedata.replace("t1", str(T1))
```

Comment: Thank Christian alot.

Comment: Glad you could figure out what the OP was after

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to output a NumPy array into a text file. In that case, you can just use:

> np.savetxt('filename.txt', T1)

Please let me know if this is not what you wanted.

Comment: actually I want to substitute T1 with a symbol in another .txt file. with this command newdata = filedata.replace('t1',T1) but it gives me error, I have to convert the T1 one first to something and then can perform the substitution but I don't know to what ?